# how to retrieve orders from ordertools component in atg or how to test orderlookup droplet api

Tags: java, atg, atg-droplet, atg-dust

iam trying to orderlookup droplet API by passing some parameters.I assume that the parameters which are mandatory is userId and organisationIds which i have passed and additionally i have also passed "state" parameter.All these params are passed thru request and then the service method of droplet is invoked.But the service method returns nothing.My goal is to check whether this droplet this retrieving the expected set of orders or not.We can use droplet invoker but i tried that way but it didnt work may be i missed something.Please help me out!!
this is my code when i tried to use OrderLookUp API

```
DynamoHttpServletRequest request = ServletUtil.getCurrentRequest();

    mTestService.setCurrentRequest(request);
    if (request == null) {
        mTestService.vlogError("Request is null.");
        Assert.fail("Request is null ");
    }
    else
    {
        Object droplet = mTestService
                .getRequestScopedComponent("OrderLookupDroplet");

        OrderLookupDroplet=(OrderLookup) droplet;
        request.setParameter("state", "submitted");
        request.setParameter("organisationIds", organizationIds);
        request.setParameter("userId", userId);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        DynamoHttpServletRequest dynRequest = (DynamoHttpServletRequest) request;
        TestingDynamoHttpServletRequest wrappedRequest = new TestingDynamoHttpServletRequest(
                dynRequest, buffer);
        TestingDynamoHttpServletResponse wrappedResponce = new TestingDynamoHttpServletResponse(
                dynRequest.getResponse());
         OrderLookupDroplet.service(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponce);
    }
```

the above sample is only part of the code..

this is the code when i tried using droplet invoker

```
DropletInvoker invoker = new DropletInvoker(mNucleus);
        invoker.getRequest().setParameter("state", "submitted");
      //  String [] siteIds = {"siteA", "siteB"};
      //  invoker.getRequest().setParameter("siteIds", Arrays.asList(siteIds));
        String [] organizationIds = {"OrgA", "OrgB"};
        invoker.getRequest().setParameter("organizationIds", organizationIds);
        String [] orderIds = {"orderautouser001OrgA" , "orderautouser001OrgB"};
        invokeDroplet(invoker, "autouser001", orderIds);
......

protected void invokeDroplet(DropletInvoker pInvoker, String pUserId, String[] pOrderIds) throws Exception
  {
    Map<String, Object> localParams = new HashMap();
    localParams.put("userId", pUserId);
    DropletResult result = pInvoker.invokeDroplet("/atg/commerce/order/OrderLookup", localParams);
    RenderedOutputParameter oparam = result.getRenderedOutputParameter("output", 0);

    assertNotNull("'output' oparam was not rendered", oparam);

    assertEquals("Check totalCount.", pOrderIds.length, oparam.getFrameParameter("totalCount"));

    List<Order> orders = (List<Order>)oparam.getFrameParameter("result");
    assertEquals("Check order array length.", pOrderIds.length, orders.size());
    for (int index = 0; index < pOrderIds.length; index++) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (Order order: orders) {
        if (pOrderIds[index].equals(order.getId())) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      assertTrue("Expected orderId " + pOrderIds[index] + " not found in result array", found);
    }
```

in first case i donno how to retrieve the orders by directly using orderlookup api....and in second case though i know how to use it ,iam still failing!! please help me out..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should't use droplets in java classes they should be used only inside jsp pages. Documentation of OrderLookup with example hot to use it on jsp page is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/ATGCommStoreGuide/html/s1730orderlookup01.html).

If you want to get orders or any other data stored in a repository you should use repository API with RQL (Repository Query Language). Example how to get data from repository you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/RepositoryGuide/html/s0305rqlexamples01.html) and RQL grammar [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/RepositoryGuide/html/s0305rqlgrammar01.html).

Comment: It is for testing purpose.How can a developer ensure that the droplet he/she developed is behaving as expected.Requirement is not getting the data here,i know there are other ways of doing it with RQL.In the question it is clearly mentioned like how to test orderlookup droplet.I have answered my own question too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for giving your opinions.Good news is we can invoke droplets from any other API

```
OrderLookup droplet = (OrderLookup) sNucleus.resolveName("/atg/commerce/order/OrderLookup");
        ServletTestUtils utils = new ServletTestUtils();
        mRequest = utils.createDynamoHttpServletRequestForSession(sNucleus, null, null);
        ServletUtil.setCurrentRequest(mRequest);
        mResponse = new DynamoHttpServletResponse();
        mRequest.setResponse(mResponse);
        mResponse.setRequest(mRequest);
        mResponse.setResponse(new GenericHttpServletResponse());
        mRequest.setParameter("userId", "publishing");

        droplet.setSearchByUserId(true);
        droplet.service(mRequest, mResponse);
        ArrayList<Order> orders = (ArrayList<Order>) mRequest.getObjectParameter("result");
```

here the "result" param is output param which this droplet sets.and the userId i have hardcoded as "publishing" which i have created.Ignore servletTestUtils class that is created by me which has not much to do with droplet theory here :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your code example, and the fact that you mention DropletInvoker that you are writing a unit test, and that this is not functional code.

If it is functional code, you really, *really*, should not invoke a droplet from another Nucleus component. A droplet exists solely to be used in a JSP page. If you need the functionality of the droplet in Java code, you should refactor the droplet into a service that holds the main logic, and a droplet that simply acts as a façade to the service to allow it to be invoked from a page.

In the case of the `OrderLookup` look droplet, you don't need to refactor anything. The service to use should be `OrderManager` or `OrderTools` depending on what you need. Note, there is a difference between Order objects and Order repository items, and you should prefer to use order objects - so only use the Order Repository directly if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.Ya this is long time back and at that time i had less knowledge on ATG.Droplet can be invoked from anywhere.Lets us say i have to do system testing and u just cant use a jsp page.Because thats UI and the site implementor can implement that i anyway...We can resolve the droplet and set some reuest param.Infact OrderLookupDroplet just needs userId rest of params are optional.it again sets the ouput params to the request.So once after i call the droplet.service() method i can retreive the output params as well.
here is the code sample